# Tornadofx: How can I reduce redundancy in table+editor of data classes?

Tags: tornadofx

I'm quite new to Kotlon, JavaFX and Tornadofx. I like what I see so far :)
(Also new to Stackoverflow, I hope I'm not stretching this too far...

I have an application to retrieves remote JSON data. That data is edited and returned back to the server as JSON.

An editable table view displays this data (containing nested properties) and an editor on the side is used to edit, as well.

I've attached a sample application which demonstrates this. It seems quite redundant to me and too complicated. I guess that there must be something wrong here :)

Thanks for any pointer / help you might provide! :)

- The code seems overly redundant to me. Ideally I'd like to stick with the data classes but was unable to make it editable with POJOs.
- Also, the way the nested address properties are used in the table seems a bit off to me. Other data classes will have addresses as well and copying the properties every time is certainly bad.
- (The model isn't writing back the changes to the POJOs. I've fixed this with a patched version of SimpleStringProperty but I'm not even sure if the way I used it is the best way.)

  ```
      package com.jadev.office

      import javafx.application.Application
      import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
      import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
      import javafx.collections.FXCollections
      import javafx.geometry.Orientation
      import tornadofx.*

      // data classes obtained by parsing JSON from remote server, will be send back to the server to update the data

      // Address should be used in several other classes
      data class Address(var street: String, var city: String, var country: String)

      data class Person(var name: String, var address: Address)

      // Editable versions to use in table and editor view, this is wrapping the original data
      // to avoid duplicating the properties
      class EditableAddress(var address: Address) {
          var streetProperty = SimpleStringProperty(address, "street", address.street)
          var cityProperty = SimpleStringProperty(address, "city", address.city)
          var countryProperty = SimpleStringProperty(address, "country", address.country)
      }

      class EditablePerson(val person: Person) {
          val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(person, "name", person.name)

          val editableAddress = EditableAddress(person.address)

          val addressProperty = SimpleObjectProperty(editableAddress)
          val streetProperty = addressProperty.select(EditableAddress::streetProperty)
          val cityProperty = addressProperty.select(EditableAddress::cityProperty)
          val countryProperty = addressProperty.select(EditableAddress::countryProperty)
      }

      class PersonViewModel : ItemViewModel<EditablePerson>() {
          var name = bind(EditablePerson::nameProperty)
          var street = bind(EditablePerson::streetProperty)
          var city = bind(EditablePerson::cityProperty)
          var country = bind(EditablePerson::countryProperty)
      }

      val persons = mutableListOf(
              Person("Adam", Address("Paradise 1", "Eden", "ED")),
              Person("Eve", Address("Paradise 1", "Eden", "ED")))

      class MainView : View() {
          val editablePersons = FXCollections.observableArrayList<EditablePerson>(persons.map { EditablePerson(it) })
          val model: PersonViewModel by inject()

          override val root = splitpane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
              tableview(editablePersons) {
                  column("Name", EditablePerson::nameProperty)
                  column("Street", EditablePerson::streetProperty)
                  column("City", EditablePerson::cityProperty)
                  column("Country", EditablePerson::countryProperty)

                  bindSelected(model)
              }

              form {
                  fieldset {
                      label("Name:")
                      textfield(model.name)

                      label("Street:")
                      textfield(model.street)

                      label("City:")
                      textfield(model.city)

                      label("Country:")
                      textfield(model.country)
                  }

                  button("Save") {
                      action {
                          save()
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          fun save() {
              //for some reason this is updating the table but not the data wrapped by SimpleStringProperty()
              model.commit()
              println("Updated person: ${model.item.person}")
              println("Updated persons: ${persons}")
          }
      }

      class SampleApp : App(MainView::class)

      fun main(args: Array<String>) {
          Application.launch(SampleApp::class.java, *args)
      }
  ```

Comment: Since you do not really have a problem you encounter, but are asking for a way to do your code better, i hereby want to point you to the [code review community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), where questions like yours are in good hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make sure to always only have one domain object and a corresponding ViewModel for that object. I like to implement `JsonModel` and handle serialization/deserialization directly there as well. I've never seen the need to optimize so that I don't use observable values where they are not needed, so I just stick to that pattern.

It's also a good idea to make sure that each object have a noargs constructor so they can be instantiated without calling a specialized constructor.

You should avoid converting between different versions of your object, you'll just run into trouble and subtle bugs as you've seen. Instead, I do the object traversal for address directly in the TableView. It's not the most beautiful code, but it's more transparent.

I do like your idea of exposing the address fields in the person view model though, so that they can be committed together with the person. I've changed your application to reflect these ideas.

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
import javafx.geometry.Orientation
import tornadofx.*

class Person() {
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var name by nameProperty

    val addressProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<Address>()
    var address by addressProperty

    constructor(name: String, address: Address): this() {
        this.name = name
        this.address = address
    }

    override fun toString() = "$name - $address"
}

class Address() {
    val streetProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var street by streetProperty

    val cityProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var city by cityProperty

    val countryProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var country by countryProperty

    constructor(street: String, city: String, country: String) : this() {
        this.street = street
        this.city = city
        this.country = country
    }

    override fun toString() = "$street, $city, $country"
}

class PersonModel : ItemViewModel<Person>() {
    val name = bind(Person::nameProperty)
    val address = bind(Person::addressProperty)

    val street = address.select(Address::streetProperty)
    val city = address.select(Address::cityProperty)
    val country = address.select(Address::countryProperty)
}

// The data would probably come from a controller in a real app
val persons = mutableListOf(
        Person("Adam", Address("Paradise 1", "Eden", "ED")),
        Person("Eve", Address("Paradise 1", "Eden", "ED"))).observable()

class MainView : View() {
    val model: PersonModel by inject()

    override val root = splitpane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
        tableview(persons) {
            column("Name", Person::nameProperty)
            column<Person, String>("Street", { it.value.addressProperty.value.streetProperty })
            column<Person, String>("City", { it.value.addressProperty.value.cityProperty })
            column<Person, String>("Country", { it.value.addressProperty.value.countryProperty })

            bindSelected(model)
        }

        form {
            fieldset {
                label("Name:")
                textfield(model.name)

                label("Street:")
                textfield(model.street)

                label("City:")
                textfield(model.city)

                label("Country:")
                textfield(model.country)
            }

            button("Save") {
                action {
                    save()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun save() {
        model.commit()
        println("Updated person: ${model.item}")
        println("Updated persons: $persons")
    }
}

class SampleApp : App(MainView::class)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<SampleApp>(args)
}
```